# JSON parsing error with Java org.json JSONObject not found

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON String that I want to parse with org.json lib:

```
JSONObject jason_clean = new JSONObject(unzipped);
        JSONArray array = jason_clean.getJSONArray("setlists");
        for (int i=0; i< array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject tempObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject meta_object = tempObject.getJSONObject("meta");
            String bank_name = meta_object.getString("name");
            System.out.println(bank_name);

            JSONArray presets_array = tempObject.getJSONArray("presets");
            System.out.println("presets_array.length(): "+presets_array.length());
            
            for (int j=0; j< presets_array.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject temp_preset_Object = presets_array.getJSONObject(j);
                //if (temp_preset_Object.has("meta")) {
                JSONObject meta_preset_object = temp_preset_Object.getJSONObject("meta");
                String preset_name = meta_preset_object.getString("name");
                System.out.println("BANK: "+i+" - "+bank_name+" || "+j+" - "+preset_name);
                //}
                
            }
        
        }
```

I get many results like I have been expected but it stops with the following error stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["meta"] not found.
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:573)
    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:766)
    at ZLibCompression.main(ZLibCompression.java:68)
```

Then I tried to test, if there is a "meta"-object (commented out in the code above). Now the parser runs through the end of the String but there are many entries missing. (Not only at that point, where it had stopped before.)
I have validated the JSON string with a software validator (and my python script can handle the whole String in the expected way.)
I'm new to JSON, so I don't know, if it could be a parser Problem or if there is an error in my code to handle this specific String.
[I've linked the JSON-String-file here.](https://aagcuxde-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/jens_kaufmann_aagcux_de/EcK9Eh18VhxJiXMfv7Wu-0gBsgDvnT6iBKB8wKDTN8UEoA?e=Ku6hYx)(8.6 MB)

I've added the formatted [output of successfully parsed elements](https://aagcuxde-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/jens_kaufmann_aagcux_de/EeJodz8x0bdJubxwdYPesjsBOGCrRra62jG4zgmZNyMpvA?e=fuB4WW)

Here are some snippets of the JSON string which are parsed or not parsed (JSONObject["meta"] not found):

with exception (line 213784 in JSON string):

```
{
     "device" : 2162692,
     "device_version" : 50397184,
     "meta" : {
      "build_sha" : "39f7f9a",
      "name" : ""
     },
```

without exception (line 304922 in JSON string):

```
{
     "device" : 2162692,
     "device_version" : 50397184,
     "meta" : {
      "build_sha" : "v2.81-16-gbdc0fd8",
      "name" : ""
     },
```

with exception (line 176330 in JSON string):

```
{
     "device" : 2162692,
     "device_version" : 50397184,
     "meta" : {
      "build_sha" : "561c612",
      "name" : "SLAP Punch"
     },
```

Answer (score 0):

It is failing here -->                 `JSONObject meta_preset_object = temp_preset_Object.getJSONObject("meta");`

presets under --- USER 4 does not have meta.

```
    "meta": {
        "name": "USER 4"
    },
    "presets": []
```

Your presets should have data similar to all the others:

"device" : ,
"device_version" : ,
"meta" : {
"build_sha" : "",
"name" : ""
},

Comment: Thanks! Oh, yes, I've overseen this part. It would not be so bad if these empty presets array wouldn't be handled. But the parser stops the 1st time on line 213784 where I have a "name" object. I thought, it could be the empty quotation marks at that point but on other places empty marks are processed without error (e.g. 304922). Another example for a error is at line 176330 - there is data given very similar to the other processed data.